# how can i auto fill one field same to other field with default text?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I have two fields when I write something in the 1st field, 2nd field auto fill up, and 2nd field have all-time show ***@gmail.com***. That means when I write something on the 1st field like **admin** 2nd field show it **admin@gmail.com**.I find some solution which only shows to write 1st filed to 2nd filed but not with default text **_@gmail.com**.

[Here is the image which shows what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3D8k.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in this simple way

```js
$("#first-field").on("keyup", function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   $("#second-field").val(value + "@gmail.com");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first-field">
<input type="text" id="second-field" placeholder="@gmail.com">
```

Comment: Thanks, @Phong.that's the answer what I want.